# Comparing means of two samples, one with 2million+ samples, other with only 200

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, chi-squared-test

I have two sets of data and a metric associated with each of them, I want to see if one category of data (e.g. males) have a tendency to have ahigher metric associated with it than the other category (e.g. females). The metric is continuous, however first category has over 2 million samples and the other only 200, is there a statistical test I can use?

Comment: The way this question is phrased and the tags you have applied suggest there is something special about the numbers 2 million and 200 in the context of a t-test for you.  What would it be?  In what way are you supposing this question differs from one where the numbers might instead be, say, 10 and 20?

Comment: It is mainly due to articles like these: http://blog.minitab.com/blog/statistics-and-quality-data-analysis/large-samples-too-much-of-a-good-thing where they emphasize the t-test giving huge significance to even the smallest of differences when the sample is too big. Also, I am not sure if such uneven sample size poses a problem as well.